# How to interpret partial of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $r$?

Tags: calculus, notation, partial-derivative

The wikipedia article on chain rule has this example:

---

Let $u(x,y) =x^2+2y$ where $x(r,t)=rsin(t)$ and $y(r,t)=sin^2(t)$.

Then $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} +\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$$

---

I intuitively think of a partial derivative as "derivative assuming all other arguments are fixed). But, in this case, $u$ has two arguments, $x,y$, both of which are changing. **So what is the interpretation of the partial of $u$ with respect to $r$**?

I get that $u$ is really a function of $r$ and $t$, that we can get by composing $f(a,b) = a^2 +2b$ with $x(r,t)=rsin(t)$ and $y(r,t)=sin^2(t)$, **but then why don't we just write $u(r,t)$ instead of $u(x,y)$?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\partial u / \partial r$ is a very common abuse of notation, which really means $\partial v / \partial r$, where $v$ is the composite function $v(r,t) = u(x(r,t),y(r,t))$.

(Writing $x=x(r,t)$ is also abuse of notation, since the symbol $x$ is used for two different things. It would be more accurate to write $x=\alpha(r,t)$ and $y=\beta(r,t)$ and then $v(r,t) = u(\alpha(r,t),\beta(r,t))$.)

Comment: Thank you.  Quick follow up question: suppose $x(r,t) = r+t$. If someone only cared about $r+t$, and not $r,t$ individually, then they could look at $\partial u/\partial x$, correct? I think I have seen some people write this last partial as $\partial u/\partial (r+t)$...

Comment: If $u$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ to begin with, then $\partial u / \partial x$ is what it is (as a function of $x$ and $y$). I don't really see what $r$ and $t$ has to do with that. And $\partial u/\partial(r+t)$ is *terrible* notation! There's no way of even guessing what's supposed to be held constant as $r+t$ varies...

Comment: Sorry, one more quick question. It wouldn't matter if $v$ was a composite function $v(r,s,t) = u(x,(r,t),y(r,s,t))$, correct? I.e. it would matter if $v$ and $u$ have a different number of arguments?

Comment: Sorry, I can't make sense of that formula. Did you mean to write something else?

Comment: Sorry. I will try again: In your answer you wrote "$\partial u / \partial r$ is a very common abuse of notation, which really means $\partial v / \partial r$, where $v$ is the composite function $v(r,t) = u(x(r,t),y(r,t))$.". **Here, all 4 functions $u,v,x,y$ are function of two variables. Would it matter if some were functions of $3$ variables and some were functions of 2 variables?** For example, what if $x$ was a function of three variables $x(r,s,t)$, would that matter?

Comment: The chain rule can handle any composite functions, of course. But if you're talking about the situation here, where some quantity $u$ can be viewed as a function of one or another set of coordinates on the same space, each oordinate system must have the same number of variables (the dimension of the space).